# Preview.app - enable links to custom URL schemes

Tags: pdf, preview

I have some PDF's with links like `file://` and `evernote://`.

Preview does not do anything when these are clicked, although right click -> open does work.

Is there a CLI option I can set to make these links work properly?

They work in Safari, Chrome.

Thanks.